MySQL ORDER BY LEAST but ignore NULL values
I have the following MySQL query that looks up ink levels and sorts based on the least value so that I can know which inks are running low. However, some of the printers are black & white and have NULL values in the C, M and Y columns. Currently with my query below the NULL values are coming to the top and being treated as essentially a 0.
SELECT * FROM ink_levels ORDER BY LEAST(ink_c, ink_m, ink_y, ink_k, ink_waste)

Is there a way to skip NULL values in my query above?
Thanks

LEAST() cannot skip NULLs. Add according COALESCE(). PS. Normalize your data, and the query will be trivial.

You could use COALESCE()  that returns the first non-null value from a list.
In your example if you replace
ORDER BY LEAST(ink_c, ink_m, ink_y, ink_k, ink_waste)

with
ORDER BY LEAST(
    COALESCE(ink_c, 99999),
    COALESCE(ink_m, 99999),
    COALESCE(ink_y, 99999),
    COALESCE(ink_k, 99999),
    COALESCE(ink_waste, 99999)
)

Make sure the number value is higher than any ink level and it should fix your issue.
By doing this  you ensure that a  high value is returned in case the ink value is null. This high value will then not be on top.

Thanks for that. works great. What if I wanted to add a WHERE clause to maintain this sort order but display results WHERE any of the ink levels is equals to or below?

I guess you could add the WHERE clause before the ORDER BY, to filter out rows where the ink level is higher than your threshold  (replace 50 with your value), then ORDER BY to get your sorted rows.
SELECT *
FROM ink_levels
WHERE
COALESCE(ink_c, 99999) <= 50 OR
COALESCE(ink_m, 99999) <= 50 OR
COALESCE(ink_y, 99999) <= 50 OR
COALESCE(ink_k, 99999) <= 50 OR
COALESCE(ink_waste, 99999) <= 50
ORDER BY LEAST(
COALESCE(ink_c, 99999),
COALESCE(ink_m, 99999),
COALESCE(ink_y, 99999),
COALESCE(ink_k, 99999),
COALESCE(ink_waste, 99999)
);

Thank you Thomas that's super helpful
